# Javascript Conditional Statement Based on Cookie Value

Tags: javascript, cookies, conditional-statements

I'm using cookies to scroll to different sections of a given page. The cookies are saved fine. Only one cookie can exist at a given time. I can see them in the application as they should be. However, there is an issue with my conditionals where only the last if statement runs.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 
  var internetcsomagcookie = null;
  var csomagcookie = "true";
  var triocsomagcookie = null;
  var tvcsomagcookie = null;


  if ((csomagcookie = "true")) {
      document.getElementById("csomag").scrollIntoView();
  }

  if ((triocsomagcookie = "true")) {
      document.getElementById("trio").scrollIntoView();
  }

  if ((internetcsomagcookie = "true")) {                                 document.getElementById("internet").scrollIntoView();
    
  }

  if ((tvcsomagcookie = "true")) {

      document.getElementById("tv").scrollIntoView();
    
  }
});
```

```css
#internet,#trio,#tv,#csomag {height:1000px;}


#internet {background:blue;}

#tv {background:red;}

#csomag {background:green;}

#trio {background:orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="csomag"></div>

<div id="trio"></div>

<div id="internet"></div>

<div id="tv"></div>
```

The issue is, that after creating any of the cookies (except for the last one - tvcsomagcookie), whenever I load the page where I want the scrolltoview to happen on, it jumps to the last ID in the code (basically the last if statement executes that scrolls to #tv), despite the tvcsomagcookie returning 'null'. So it runs when it should not.

Comment: How do you know only the last one runs? Can you show what the cookie values are when this runs incorrectly?

Comment: Sure, if I add: console.log(csomagcookie);
  console.log(triocsomagcookie);
  console.log(internetcsomagcookie);
  console.log(tvcsomagcookie); and only create csomagcookie for example, I get true
null
null
null (and it jumps to #tv)

Comment: You should update your post to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Are these cookies mutually exclusive? As in, will only one exist/be true at a time?

Comment: Please update your original post, per the [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) link. External links can break, leaving future readers hanging.

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If statements were originally posted with = (which is for assignment) instead of == for comparison. Updating this inside the code fixed the issue.